# Shortcut to compute $2^{(p+1)/4}\bmod p$, where $p$ is prime and $p\equiv3\pmod4$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

It's given a prime $p$ with $p\equiv3\pmod4$.

What shortcut (if any) is there to compute $x=2^{(p+1)/4}\bmod p$, compared to a general algorithm to compute $x=2^k\bmod p$ applied for $k=(p+1)/4$ ?

---

I'm aware that

- $x^2\equiv-2\pmod p$ if $p\equiv3\pmod8$, and $x^2\equiv2\pmod p$ if $p\equiv7\pmod8$, but I see no way to use that;
- we can compute $2^k\bmod p$ nearly twice faster than $m^k\bmod p$ for a random $m\in[0,p)$, for the range of $p$ I'm interested in (some thousands bits).

---

The application would be in computing a [Rabin signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_signature_algorithm) using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: The classical algorithm for solving $x^2\equiv2\pmod p$ (say) is actually to compute $2^{(p+1)/4}\pmod p$ ... so I don't think there's going to be any theoretical shortcut (could be wrong though).